# How to link two bar charts in altair?

Tags: vega, altair

I'm having trouble with a fairly simple interaction because I don't understand the language of altair very much.

Say I have a dataframe containing the state, county and population.

I want to create one bar chart showing states and their populations and another showing counties and their populations.

Clicking on a state populates the next bar chart with county names, and their populations. Clicking away from any state in the first chart empties out the county chart again.

Simple master/detail or context/focus pair of charts.

Additonally, I'm not clear how to debug this either. Is there a way to print the selected state to the console?

Here is some data I pulled from wikipedia (unable to share actual work data):

`State,County,Land Area
California,Los Angeles, 10510 
Illinois,Cook, 2448 
Texas,Harris, 4412 
Arizona,Maricopa, 23828 
California,San Diego, 10895 
California,Orange, 2048 
Florida,Miami-Dade, 4915 
New York,Kings, 183 
Texas,Dallas, 2257 
New York,Queens, 281 
California,Riverside, 18665 
California,San Bernardino, 51947`

When I click on the bar representing California in the first chart, the second chart should populate with Los Angeles, San Diego, Orange, Riverside and San Bernadino. When I click on New York in the first chart, the second chart should populate with Kings and Queens.

Comment: Hello, could you share some data? Here is a link that could be useful https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/interactive_layered_crossfilter.html

Comment: @FlorianGD added some test data. I saw the various interval selection examples but am not able to adapt them to code where a single click of a bar in Chart 1 changes chart 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does what you want I believe. The idea is to create a selection on a chart, and use this to filter the second one.

```py
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

states_str = """State,County,Land Area
California,Los Angeles, 10510 
Illinois,Cook, 2448 
Texas,Harris, 4412 
Arizona,Maricopa, 23828 
California,San Diego, 10895 
California,Orange, 2048 
Florida,Miami-Dade, 4915 
New York,Kings, 183 
Texas,Dallas, 2257 
New York,Queens, 281 
California,Riverside, 18665 
California,San Bernardino, 51947
"""

states_df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(states_str))

state_selector = alt.selection_multi(fields=['State'])

chart_states = alt.Chart(states_df).mark_bar().encode(
    x=alt.X('State:N'),
    y=alt.Y('count():Q')
).add_selection(state_selector)

chart_county = alt.Chart(states_df).mark_bar().encode(
    x=alt.X('County:N'),
    y=alt.Y('count():Q')
).transform_filter(state_selector)

chart_states | chart_county
```

Chart when nothing is selected

[image]

Chart after clicking on California on the first chart.
[image]

<sup>Created on 2018-11-21 by the [reprexpy package](https://github.com/crew102/reprexpy)</sup>

Comment: I hadn't thought of using selection_multi (instead of selection_single). I ended up building multi-level charts (think state, county, city). What an awesome tool and thanks for your hep.